# What does per user mean for DocuSign developer account

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on integrating a web app with DocuSign, for intermediate and advanced accounts you pay per user. I would like to know what per user means in this context?

As far as I understand the developer account provides me with an integration key that I can use to authenticate against DocuSign, why might I need multiple users?

[developer plans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZrLT.png)

Answer (score 0):

"DocuSign Account" - an organizational space that encompasses the features and capabilities (account plan) that come with the particular subscription purchased, e.g. "standard", "business pro", "enterprise pro", etc.

"User" - a person or entity with access (login credentials) to one or more DocuSign Accounts.

"Member" - a User that is a member of a particular DocuSign Account.

Examples:
A small company may purchase a seat-based "Standard" license subscription for 20 seats.  They would then be provisioned with one DocuSign Account with an initial Admin User.  The Admin User can then add up to 19 additional users as members of the account.

A large company may purchase an "Enterprise Pro" subscription for a volume of envelope transactions rather than seats.  They might ask to have 4 accounts provisioned: 1 for US Sales team, 1 for Europe Sales team, 1 for Procurement team, and one for HR team.  Each would have administrators that would then add users from their teams.  There may be some users that have memberships in more than one account, e.g. Sales GVP with membership in both Sales accounts, IT admin team members with memberships in all 4 accounts as admins, etc.

HTH

Comment: Forgot to mention - Integration Key is the "client ID" for the integration and is unrelated to a User or Users.  You only need one IK for an integration, regardless of how many users and accounts are leveraging the integration.  The only time you need >1 IK is if your software deploys to environments you don't control or can't protect.  IK Secrets or RSA Keypairs must be secured.

Comment: I understand how users make sense for a general DocuSign plan, but why would you need users for a developer plan? What does the user in this sense represent? And why does the starter pack not mention pricing based on users whilst the other plans do?
My only guess would be that users in this sense refers to the organization, e.g I wouldn't be able to have users from two different organizations access DocuSign through my integration unless I have subscribed to a plan with two users (ie organizations)
Do you understand my confusion? 
Thanks!

Comment: The first user in an account always has the Administrator permission profile.  Technically, for your developer account you only need one user.  However, to avoid losing access to the account, you should add some other dev team members as admins as well. 
Also, to test your integration, you may want to have some test users in your account, or even set up additional accounts with separate test users to represent multiple business units in your enterprise, or multiple customer accounts if you are an ISV.